# How to change a State of a StatefulWidget inside a StatelessWidget?

Tags: dart, widget, flutter, state, statefulwidget

Just testing out flutter. The code sample below is a very simple flutter app. The problem is that I don't know how to call the setState() function inside the TestTextState class in order to change the text each time when the change button is pressed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test app',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Test"),
        ),
        body: new Test(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  final TestText testText = new TestText();

  void change() {
    testText.text == "original" ? testText.set("changed") : testText.set("original");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: [
        testText,
        new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("change"),
            onPressed: () => change(),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}

class TestText extends StatefulWidget {

  String text = "original";

  void set(String str) {
    this.text = str;
  }

  @override
  TestTextState createState() => new TestTextState();
}

class TestTextState extends State<TestText> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(this.widget.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have approached this problem by initializing the _TestTextState as the final property of the TestText widget which allows to simply update the state when the change button is pressed. It seems like a simple solution but I'm not sure whether it's a good practice.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test app',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Test"),
        ),
        body: new Test(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  final _TestText text = new _TestText();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
        children: [
          text,
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("change"),
            onPressed: () => text.update(),
          ),
        ]
    );
  }
}

class TestText extends StatefulWidget {

  final _TestTextState state = new _TestTextState();

  void update() {
    state.change();
  }

  @override
  _TestTextState createState() => state;
}

class _TestTextState extends State<TestText> {

  String text = "original";

  void change() {
    setState(() {
      this.text = this.text == "original" ? "changed" : "original";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(this.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thier is no way to do so. any how you have to convert your **[StatelessWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)** to **[StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. So if I have several different pages in my app and all of them share the one dynamic text widget, does it mean that I have to convert all my screens to StatefulWidgets? How would it reflect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on your existing code

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  final StreamController<String> streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TestText testText = TestText(streamController.stream);
    return new Column(children: [
      testText,
      new RaisedButton(
        child: Text("change"),
        onPressed: () {
          String text = testText.text == "original" ? "changed" : "original";
          streamController.add(text);
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class TestText extends StatefulWidget {
  TestText(this.stream);
  final Stream<String> stream;
  String text = "original";

  @override
  TestTextState createState() => new TestTextState();
}

class TestTextState extends State<TestText> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.stream.listen((str) {
      setState(() {
        widget.text = str;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.text);
  }
}
```

But it's not the best idea - to use non-final field inside Stateful Widget

P.S.
You can also use this - [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model)

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response. Adding the StreamController seems like a good idea. How the solution with no non-final field would look like? Is that even possible?

Comment: Store this field inside `TestTextState`, and inside `listen` check current value of `text`- for example. In this case you can send any data to stream - type doesn't matter